# extract audio data from a multipart response

Tags: ios, nsdata, avaudioplayer, alamofire

I am getting following data from a post http request

```
--Boundary

Content-Type: application/json

{"messageHeader":{},"messageBody":{"directives":[{"namespace":"SpeechSynthesizer","name":"speak","payload":{"contentIdentifier":"******","audioContent":"cid:******"}}]}}

--Boundary

Content-ID: <********>

Content-Type: audio/mpeg

****audio bytes****

--Boundary

Content-ID: <********>

Content-Type: audio/mpeg

****audio bytes****

--Boundary--
```

This entire response is in NSData and I want to go ahead and play the audio in the app using AVPlayer.

I tried get subdata from using subdataWithRange(NSRange) on the response data and play it from the AVPlayer and it did not work.

It would be great if anyone suggest any neater way using any swift library?

Comment: Try saving all audio bytes to a file with expected extension, and then try playing the file manually in iTunes to ensure it's not an issue with how you're saving the audio bytes. NOTE - I am unsure if AVPlayer requires uncompressed audio, or if it handles the decompression for you.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. I also want to add how exactly I copied.
I write the data into a file using 
  data?.writeToFile("data.txt", options:  NSDataWritingOptions.AtomicWrite)

and then I open the file and manually copy the presumable audio bytes into and file change the extension to mpeg/mp3 and try to play it, the itunes cannot open it.